# Android Studio and Capacitor cannot finde console.log() output

Tags: android-studio, capacitor

I have a Angular Application that i converted via Capacitor to a Android App. If i start my app in Android Studio i cannot access my Nodejs. Therefor i want to use the `console.log()` to see where my problem is.

But i cant find an output of my log, even though its there in the web console.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can see Capacitor logs in two different places.

1. Chrome remote inspector, just type this in your Desktop Chrome `chrome://inspect/#devices` and your device should appear there and a list of webs and apps that can be debugged, choose your app and you'll see all the `console.log`s there.
2. Logcat. Inside Android Studio on the bottom on the screen there should be a Logcat section, if you click it it should show `console.log` messages and also native messages.

Comment: After entering chrome://inspect/#devices  - how do I "choose your app" from here? They don't seem clickable?

Thanks!

Comment: is your app running? in the screenshot I don't see any apps listed

Comment: I have it running inside Android Studio (Arctic Fox).

Comment: You should see something like, 'Android SDK built for x86
#EMULATOR-5554' and then a link will show up under it stating, `inspect`. This will allow seeing console messages.